# Преобразование NPM модуля в обычный скрипт JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html5, npm

Можно ли преобразовать NPM модуль в один файл JS который можно будет использовать на обычном сайте а не в Node.JS и подключать просто вот так:

```html
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

Comment: Можно, но для этого понадобится NPM и Node.js

Comment: Зависит от того, что делает данный модуль.

Comment: К примеру https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsmediatags
На GitHub есть его простая JS версия, но она больше не обновляется и в ней получаются не все данные.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsmediatags#browser